# How to exclude weekend (Sunday only) to DATEDIFF in Tableau?

Tags: data-visualization, data-science, tableau-api, calculated-field, tableau-desktop

So my current formula is this: **DATEDIFF('day', MIN([Date]),MAX([Date]))**.

How do I exclude sundays? and holidays.

Comment: Deduct `datediff('week'...)`? Not sure how Tableau works but I think that would count the number of week transitions (where week starts on Sunday anyway.)

Comment: Offset by week transitions. In case first day is Sunday start range one day earlier: `- DATEDIFF('week', MIN([Date]-1),MAX([Date]), 'sunday')`

Comment: Hi! @shawnt00. Additional question though. What if I want the complete days in a month to appear since in my raw data for some categories has no date entry for example:

Agent A     January 1
Agent A     January 1
Agent A     January 3

So it only count 2 days (jan 1 & 3).

I will be using this as a divisor to get the average that's why I needed the complete days.

Comment: I don't know enough about your problem or Tableau to answer. Often this is a join against a calendar table. Try searching for "densification".